# Subsetting on a tibble using "[]" gives "object not found" error

Tags: r, dplyr

The article on dplyr [here](http://seananderson.ca/2014/09/13/dplyr-intro.html) says "[]" (square brackets) can be used to subset filtered Tibbles like this:

```
filter(mammals, adult_body_mass_g > 1e7)[ , 3]
```

But I am getting an "object not found" error. 
Here is the replication of the error on a more known dataset "iris"

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length>6) [,c(1:3)]
```

> Error in filter_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
>     object 'Sepal.Length' not found

I also want to mention that I am deliberately not preferring to use the native subsetting in dplyr using `select()` as I need a vector output and not a data frame on a single column. Unfortunately, dplyr always forces a data frame output (for good reasons).

Comment: Is `Sepal.Length`  a column in your `mammals` data frame? It seems like you posted an error message that doesn't correspond to the code.

Comment: Sorry, the error message is not from mammals. But from **iris** dataset. I can paste the full reproduction of error with iris if you want. thought it was self-explanatory.

Comment: added the code that corresponds to the error.

Comment: `filter(iris,Sepal.Length>6)[,c(1:3)]` works though.

Comment: @Lamia: that's right! So the piped operation is a different syntax for using subsetting. Anyway, I got the solution from akaDrHouse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an extra pipe:

```
iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length>6) %>% .[,1:3]
```

Sorry, forgot the `.` before the brackets.

Note: Your code will probably be more readable if you stick to the tidyverse syntax and use select as the last operation.

```
iris %>%
     filter(Sepal.Length > 6) %>%
     select(1:3)
```

Comment: Nopes. Get this error now.
_Error: unexpected '[' in "iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length>6) %>% ["_

Comment: @sanjmeh had a typo.  Add the `.` before brackets.

Comment: Super duper! Works now. Thanks.

Comment: On your comment @akaDrHouse I would have preferred `select` but the problem is dplyr does not drop levels when only ONE column is selected. I want one column only as a vector output. So I'll use 
`iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length>6) %>% .[,3]`

Answer (score 2):

The `dplyr`-native way of doing this is to use `select`:

```
iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length > 6) %>% select(1:3)
```

You could also use `{}` so that the filtering is done before `[` is applied:

```
{iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length>6)}[,c(1:3)]
```

Or, as suggested in another answer, use the `.` notation to indicated where the data should go in relation to `[`:

```
iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length>6) %>% .[,1:3]
```

You can also load `magrittr` explicitly and use `extract`, which is a "pipe-able" version of `[`:

```
library(magrittr)
iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length>6) %>% extract( ,1:3)
```

---

The blog entry you reference is old in `dplyr` time - about 3 years old. `dplyr` has been changing a lot. I don't know whether the blog's suggestion worked at the time it was written or not, but I'd recommend finding more recent sources to learn about this frequently changing package.

Comment: You are correct on the native use of dplyr. But as mentioned by me in previous comments, why I didn't want to use `select` is because I wanted a vector instead of a dataframe when I select only ONE column. dplyr does not allow this.

Comment: It's nice to include info like that in the question. And to use an example that matches your use case. It can make the question more useful to future users and the answers more relevant.

Comment: Added the reason of not using native subsetting.